# put a text on the left and an image on the right

Tags: minipage

I would put a text on the left and an image on the right. I use *minipage* env but the image goes left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}

\lipsum[66] \newline

\lipsum[66] \newline

\lipsum[66]

\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment please.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}

\lipsum[3] 

\end{minipage}% Don't leave empty lines and empty chars between minipages
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your help.

Comment: Welcome,,, Happy TeXing